# Configure controls in a FormGroup to not return value

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible, when defining a FormGroup instance, to set some properties to not return value when using `.getRawValues` or any other?

I know that disabled controls does not return when using `.value`, but I need to set other controls to not return value.

Here is a FormGroup definition:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
{
  id: [null],
  prop1: [null, Validators.required],
  prop2: [null, Validators.required],
  prop3: [null, ... something like Ignore..]
});
```

So when using:

```
this.form.getRawValue()
```

I get:

```
{id, prop1, prop2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy the form values and remove unwanted properties.

```
let {prop2, ...valuesYouWant} = yourFormValues
```